# Angular Nested Component not rendering with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I am simply trying to nest a component inside a component and pass an array as the ngFor of the nested component.  The issue is the array is from an observable and nothing is rendering for the nested component.  I can see the observable returning in the browser console so I know everything is working up to the point of the nested component render.  I know it has something to do with the render occurring before the observable returning data but I have not been able to find documentation or online information (or SO questions) that have pointed me to what I am missing.

Here is the code..

srv-data.service.ts:

```js
interface IWeek {
  id: number;
  weeknumofyear: number;
  year: number;
  holidaymontype: number;
  holidaytuetype: number;
  holidaywedtype: number;
  holidaythutype: number;
  holidayfritype: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class SrvDataService {
  errorMessage: any;
  private _apiUrl = 'http://172.16.194.250:99/api/';
  weeks$: Observable<IWeek[]>;
  weeks: IWeek[] = [];

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
      this.getWeeks()
      .subscribe(weeks$ => this.weeks = weeks$,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);      
  }

  getWeeks(): Observable<IWeek[]> {
    return this._http.get<IWeek[]>(this._apiUrl + 'Weeks')
    .do(data => console.log('Weeks from getWeeks(): ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SrvDataService } from './services/srv-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {
  weeks: IWeek[] = [];

  constructor (public dataService: SrvDataService) {
      this.weeks = this.dataService.weeks;
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<div>
In app.component {{ weeks }}
    <app-week *ngFor="let week of weeks; index as i; first as isFirst" [week]="week"></app-week>
</div>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Delete subscribe from the service and use async Pipe inside your app.component.html:

```
<div>
  In app.component {{ weeks }}
  <app-week *ngFor="let week of weeks | async; index as i; first as isFirst"
            [week]="week">
  </app-week>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that and still not rendering the component (or the {{ weeks}}).

Answer (score 0):

Don't Subscribe the Observable in Service, Try Subscribing it in Components ngOnInit and assign the response in "this.weeks". Hope That will help.

Debug weeks like "{{weeks | json}}". There you should see whole object else you will see "[object Object]".

If that Doesnot work, Please share it over stackblitz, i can fix it for you